LVM using ansible - need to allocate based on size
I need to mount 4 filesystems into sd* devices based on size. If sda- 100, sdb -200 and sdc -50 and sdd -100 GB respectively then I need to mount my app filesystems into these 4 devices based on size.

/abc should go to /dev/sdb as it needs 200 GB
/cde should go to /dev/sda or /dev/sdd as it needs 100 GB
/efg should go to /dev/sda or /dev/sdd  as it too needs 100 GB and so on


Right now, I have below code which I am running 4 times for 4 filesystems:
I was also trying to see how I can loop these code block instead of using it 4 times
    - name: Create physical partition
      parted:
        device: "{{ abc_physical_volume }}"
        number: 1
        flags: [lvm]
        state: present
    - name: Create volume group
      lvg:
       vg: "{{ abc_volume_group }}"
       pvs: "{{ abc_physical_volume }}1"
       pesize: 16
    - name: Create logical volume
      lvol:
        vg: "{{ abc_volume_group }}"
        lv: "{{ abc_logical_volume }}"
        size: 100%FREE
        force: yes
    - name: Create directory if does not exist
      file:
        path: {{ abc_mountpoint }}
        state: directory
        mode: '0755'
    - name: Format the xfs file system
      filesystem:
        fstype: xfs
        state: present
        dev: "{{ abc_filesystem_path }}"
    - name: update fstab
      mount: 
        path: /abc
        src: /dev/mapper/abcvg-abclv
        fstype: xfs
        state: mounted


You can create a list of dictionaries that would store the allocation rules, move your code into a separate task file, and include it in a loop iterating over the said list.
Note that I can't test it on my machine so you might need to check the code and maybe correct it a bit, but it shows the idea:
# playbook.yaml
---
- name: LVM using Ansible - need to allocate based on size
  hosts: all
  vars:
    fs_mapping_rules:
      - fs: /abc
        vg: abcvg
        lv: abclv
        size: 200
        device: /dev/sdb
      - fs: /cde
        vg: cdevg
        lv: cdelv
        size: 100
        device: /dev/sda
      - fs: /efg
        vg: efgvg
        lv: efglv
        size: 100
        device: /dev/sdd
      - fs: /ghj
        vg: ghjvg
        lv: ghjlv
        size: 50
        device: /dev/sdc
  tasks:
    - name: Allocate based on size
      include_tasks: allocate.yaml
      loop: "{{ fs_mapping_rules }}"

Of course, that allocate.yaml should be modified a bit to work in a loop:
# allocate.yaml
---
- name: Create physical partition
  parted:
    device: "{{ item.device }}"
    number: 1
    flags: [ lvm ]
    state: present

- name: Create volume group
  lvg:
    vg: "{{ item.vg }}"
    pvs: "{{ item.device }}1"
    pesize: 16

- name: Create logical volume
  lvol:
    vg: "{{ item.vg }}"
    lv: "{{ item.lv }}"
    size: 100%FREE
    force: yes

- name: Create directory if does not exist
  file:
    path: "{{ item.fs }}"
    state: directory
    mode: '0755'

- name: Format the xfs file system
  filesystem:
    fstype: xfs
    state: present
    dev: "{{ item.device }}"

- name: update fstab
  mount:
    path: "{{ item.fs }}"
    src: "/dev/mapper/{{ item.vg }}-{{ item.lv }}"
    fstype: xfs
    state: mounted


Thanks, Alexander, for your response. I tested and made some changes (as for my case, the sizing comes from terraform and is not hardcoded) but what I observed that it is mounting abc on /dev/sdb even though it is 100 GB. It is considering the device name and not assigning based on disk size
